# Changing docker cpu, ram, drive configuration

Tags: docker, minikube

I'm trying to locally build [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/docs/development-guide.md) application. Unfortunately provided `skaffold run` command generates an error `build [adservice] failed: exit status 127. Docker build ran into internal error. Please retry.`

I suspect it's because I didn't set correct cpu, ram, and hard drive settings. And I didn't do it because such settings do not exist. I have been trying to figure it out for two hours and I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Docker desktop on windows (WSL2 backend) and want to configure the resources it is using (cpu,ram), you should create a file named `.wslconfig` in your user profile directory (you can find it by typing `%userprofile%` in Windows Start or in File explorer where you specify path to directory), usually it looks like this `C:\Users\MyUserName` 
You can configre the parameters in the file as follows:

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4 GB
processors=4 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use 4 virtual processors
```